# Is akshaya(अक्षय) used as substitute of thousands (numbers) any where?

Tags: scripture, terminology

**Akshaya** in Hindu texts is generally translated as everlasting, forever etc.,

Does Akshaya is used anywhere in the scriptures as a substitute for large numbers (hundreds, thousands etc.,)?

Comment: Akshaya basically means infinte or that does not end/exhaust.. do u hv anything specific while asking this question?

Comment: @Rickross the specific is *Akshaya Naraka* and in some preachings I heard that akshaya may be substitute by a large number like thousands.. So I'm asking for it.

Comment: the word 'sahasra' is used to denote both thousand and infinite, as evident in purusha suktam